# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null

Tags: javascript, html, web

I'm getting the error mentioned in the title and from what I saw it seems to be quite a popular question.

EDIT: I know that the error means that the element I'm trying to edit is null but it only becomes null after the sleep function is executed.

So what is happening here is that I want to make the information displayed on a certain div dynamic and I'm using the sleep function shown below. I'm getting the error at the line that is directly after it. what might be the cause here? For some reason, the script doesn't recognize the element I want after I call the sleep() function. if you have a better way fo accomplishing what I described above then you're welcome to post your suggestions.

```
    document.getElementById("box_2_info_" + i).style.display = "contents";
            document.getElementById("box_2_info_" + i).className += " animate-bottom";
            await sleep(3000);
            //error below -->
            document.getElementById("box_2_info_" + i).style.display = "none";
```

Here's my sleep function

```
    function sleep(ms) {
            return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
    };
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you don't wait the DOM to be ready, so the DOM element is not available yet.

If you replace

`document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", run, false);`

with

`run()`

You'll get the same error

```js
(function () {
  "use strict";

  const run = async () => {
    var i = 0;
    var el = document.getElementById("box_2_info_" + i);

    el.style.display = "contents";
    el.classList.add("animate-bottom");
    console.log("sleeping...");
    await sleep(3000);
    console.log("awake!");
    el.style.display = "none";
  };

  const sleep = (ms) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
  };

  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", run, false);
  // run();
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="box_2_info_0"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

All this error means is that the property you are trying to edit, in this case the element with an id `"box_2_info_" + i`does not exist. I would double-check your markup to make sure that this property exists.

Comment: That wasn't the problem as I specified in the question. Thanks though.